# Generating unique random number with condition Snowflake

Tags: sql, random, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence, dml

I would like to generate some UNIQUE random numbers in Snowflake with a specific starting/ending point. I would like for the numbers to start at 1,000 and end at 1,000,000.

Another requirement is joining a string at the beginning of these numbers.

So far I have been using this statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT('TEST-' , uniform(10000, 99000, RANDOM()));
```

Which works as expected and gives me the output of e.g. 'TEST-31633'.

However the problem is I am generating these for a large amount of rows, and I need for them to be completely unique.

I have heard of the 'SEQ1' functions however not sure how I could specify a starting point as well as adding a 'TEST-' with the CONCAT function at the beginning. Ideally they won't be in a strict sequence but differ from each other.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to guarantee uniqueness from a random number generator function unless you use some kind of calculated part. For example:

```
create or replace table testX as
select  CONCAT('TEST-' , to_char(seq4(),'0000'),  
uniform(100000, 990000, random())) c 
from table(generator(rowcount => 1000));
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect, I have marked as the answer. One more thing if you have a moment: The end goal here is to replace some numbers with unique TEST-xxxx in a columns of a table.

Is there any change I can include the above statement as a part of a nested query? I never managed to use the generator table in such a way. Say I need row1 & row2 from table A, and want to attach these random number as a third column FROM table(generator...

Or perhaps even simply use the query to UPDATE table Set Row 1 = ?

Comment: This should work: UPDATE tableName Set col3 = CONCAT('TEST-' , to_char(seq4(),'0000'),  
uniform(100000, 990000, random()));

Answer (score 1):

Any time it's required to assign unique random numbers inside a range, that's best handled through a shuffle rather than generation of new random numbers. Simply generate the sequence, and then shuffle its order.

Depending on the use case, you could simply generate the rows and use `order by random()` with a limit on the number selected:

```
select * from (
select 'TEST-' || (seq4() + 10000)::string as MY_TEST_ID
from table(generator(rowcount => 89000))
) order by random() limit 10000
;
```

A general-purpose solution to this problem is more complex but certainly possible. A JavaScript UDTF can populate an array with all values in the range and shuffle it. Using a window function on the JavaScript UDTF to ensure that the rows are distributed in a single block, it will allow creation of unique random integers in a range in any SQL statement.

First, create the table functions:

```
create or replace function UNIQUE_RANDOM_INTEGERS(LBOUND float, UBOUND float)
returns table (UNIQUE_RAND_INT float)
language javascript
strict volatile
as
$$
{
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
        this.lBound = argumentInfo.LBOUND.constValue;
        this.uBound = argumentInfo.UBOUND.constValue;
        this.rSpace = this.uBound - this.lBound + 1;
        
        if (this.lBound >= this.uBound) throw new Error(">>>  LBOUND and UBOUND must be constants and UBOUND must be greater than LBOUND <<<");
        if (this.rSpace > 25000000) throw new Error (">>> The difference between LBOUND and UBOUND must be 25,000,000 or less.");
        
        this.rands = new Array(this.rSpace);
        this.currentRow = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.rands.length; i++) {
            this.rands[i] = this.lBound + i;
        }
        this.rands = shuffle(this.rands);
        
        function shuffle(array) {
            let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
            while (currentIndex != 0) {
                randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                currentIndex--;
                [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
            }
            return array;
        }
    },
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        //
    },
    finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.rSpace; i++) {
            rowWriter.writeRow({UNIQUE_RAND_INT:this.rands[i]});
        }
    },
}
$$;

create or replace function UNIQUE_RANDOM_INTEGERS(LBOUND int, UBOUND int)
returns table(UNIQUE_RAND_INT int)
language sql
as
$$
    select UNIQUE_RAND_INT::int from table(UNIQUE_RANDOM_INTEGERS(LBOUND::float, UBOUND::float) over (partition by 1))
$$;
```

You can then generate unique random numbers in a range using this SQL:

```
select 'TEST-' || UNIQUE_RAND_INT as MY_RAND_VAL
from table(unique_random_integers(10000, 99000));
```

Comment: agreed, it's not "random" if it's also not repeating for an arbitrary window. Otherwise it's like saying I want 100 rolls of a 1d6 and have no repeats.

Answer (score 1):

Another shuffle answer:

some setup:

```
set range_start = 1;
set range_end = 10;
set range_len = $range_end - $range_start;
set name_width = 6;
```

```
select 
    'row_' ||lpad(row_number()over(order by true),$name_width,0) as row_num
from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => $range_len));
```

gives:

| ROW_NUM |
| --- |
| row_000001 |
| row_000002 |
| row_000003 |
| row_000004 |
| row_000005 |
| row_000006 |
| row_000007 |
| row_000008 |
| row_000009 |

so no repeats, now to shuffle them, just give them and random value and order by that:

```
select 
    'row_' ||lpad(row_number()over(order by true),$name_width,0) as row_num
    ,random() as rnd_order
from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => $range_len))
order by rnd_order;
```

| ROW_NUM | RND_ORDER |
| --- | --- |
| row_000002 | -7,719,769,195,714,581,512 |
| row_000007 | -7,227,137,977,152,948,936 |
| row_000004 | -4,651,924,808,142,841,706 |
| row_000005 | -4,571,360,566,799,746,506 |
| row_000003 | -1,059,648,113,216,115,246 |
| row_000008 | 1,056,363,703,661,911,623 |
| row_000001 | 2,281,704,740,829,606,855 |
| row_000006 | 5,648,204,845,936,012,521 |
| row_000009 | 8,998,464,501,571,068,967 |

change the setup to be in the relm of what you want:

```
set range_start = 1000;
set range_end = 1000000;
set range_len = $range_end - $range_start;
```

Now if you only wanted 500K answers instead of 9,999K, slap a limit 500000 on the end..

Answer (score 0):

did you try with UNIFORM, may be this will work for you.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/uniform.html

```
select  CONCAT('TEST-' , uniform(10000, 99000, random())) from table(generator(rowcount => 100));
```

Comment: Yes I have the UNIFORM in my above query, unfortunately this still produces duplicates

Comment: One way you could try is to use UNIFORM 2 times in a different range and CONCAT the string, this may give you unique.. You can generate a row_numner() and use that number to append to the string.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html